# Did a suicidal woman talk a police officer into jumping with her?

Tags: police, suicide

Right now, memes featuring a supposed news paper article stating "SUICIDE WOMAN TALKS COP INTO JUMPING WITH HER!" are going around. For example:

[image: Suicide Woman Talks Cop into Jumping with Her]

More examples (not displayed as images to save space, original URLs credited, but some linked to SE imgur):

- [https://pics.onsizzle.com/suicide-woman-talks-cop-into-jumping-with-her-ah-yes-67526315.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnvs6.png)
- [https://pics.me.me/suicide-woman-talks-cop-into-jumping-with-her-charisma-my-67527662.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eUTK.png)
- [https://pics.awwmemes.com/suicide-woman-talks-cop-into-jumping-with-her-joe-regen-67515768.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b355g.png)
- https://meme.xyz/uploads/posts/t/l-28454-suicide-woman-talsk-cop-into-jumping-with-her-speech-100.jpg

Is there any truth to this? Did someone really convince a police officer sent out to help them avoid suicide to commit suicide together?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This story is from the [October 25, 1994 issue of the Weekly World News](https://books.google.com/books?id=XfIDAAAAMBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), page 2:
[image]

The [Weekly World News](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weekly_World_News) had a reputation for posting outrageous stories made up from whole cloth.

While I cannot prove that this particular story is false, I can give you some context to show the level of journalistic standards held by this publication. This same issue also included such stories as:

- 65-million-year-old lug nut discovered in Arizona!
- Dad breaks croc's neck with his bare hands!
- Security guard superglues burglar to wall!
- Two bandits stick up the same bank at the same time!
- Hot-blooded lady Bigfoot stalking farm worker!
- Ancient writings reveal Egyptian pharaoh flew in alien spaceship!
- Japan's secret plan to launch their junk cars into orbit

Comment: How can you mention WWN stories and not include their most spectacularly successful invention, [Batboy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bat_Boy_(character))?

Comment: There happened to be no stories about Batboy in this particular issue. Otherwise I certainly would have including him on the list.

Comment: Taking me back to my childhood. I don't think WWN *ever* intended to be journalistic. Only look like it, you know, for the lols.

Comment: @frеdsbend Their official position (at least at the time this story was published) was that their stories were factual, but I don't think they were trying very hard to convince anyone. I certainly never met anyone who actually took these stories seriously.

Comment: covid-boredom now has me wanting to look into that "Hot-blooded lady Bigfoot" one

Comment: WWN was to journalism what WWE is to sports.

Comment: Now we'll need to post 7 more questions

Comment: Are there cold-blooded Bigfoots? I thought it was pretty much taken for granted that Bigfoot is a mammal. As for the two robbers one, it doesn't likely all that farfetched.

Comment: @Acccumulation "Hot-blooded" is meant in the figurative sense here, meaning "lustful". The story about two robbers claimed that two independent bank robbers happened to show up to rob the same bank at exactly the same time, with each of them expecting to be the only robber there. That seems rather farfetched to me.

Comment: @barbecue - Now how am i gonna get anything done.  The related links on that page are "Fictional Characters invented in 1992", "Fictional Characters from West Virginia", and "Fictional Bats".  That is some spicy reading material.

Comment: I bet the building depicted here is actually located in Manhattan.

Comment: This good answer would be even more complete if it listed the spurious "eyeball scam" news that can be read in the bottom-right of the image. PEOPLE HAVE THE RIGHT TO KNOW !

Comment: @Evargalo There were so many good examples to choose from! I had to pick and choose. The eyeball scam article is indeed outrageous, but I didn't choose it because the entire "story" is just a single 26-word sentence whose main purpose seems to be to fill up a small gap on the page. The WWN had a lot of those postage-stamp-sized articles before they moved to an all-web format.